# $f(x)=x$ if $x \in\mathbb Q$. $f(x)=0$ if $x \in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$. show that the function is discontinuous on $\mathbb Q$\{0}

Tags: real-analysis

I know how to prove this using sequential criterion. i have on mind a different proof, just wanna check if its correct:

lets show that $\lim_{x\to q} f(x)$ doesn't equal $f(q)=q$ ($q$ is a rational number)

then there exist $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-q|>\epsilon$ for every $S>0$ and $|x-q|< S$

let $\epsilon=q/2$ and choose a irrational number $r\in(q-S,q+S)$
then $|f(x)-q|=|f(r)-q|=|0-q|=q= 2\epsilon>\epsilon$ when $r\in|x-q|<S$

Comment: The function is not discontinuous at every point of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: i mean discontinuous on Q/{0}

Comment: Please edit the Q to say what you mean.

Comment: MathJax has some little shortcuts. I found that \Bbb is the same as \mathbb

Answer (score 1):

Some points

- You can't say "then" if you've done nothing to prove it.
- The next line is the proof that there exists **one** bad choice of $x$. This is strictly weaker than the previous line "for every $S>0$ and $|x-q|<S$ which I can only understand to mean "for all $S$ and $x$ such that $S>0$ and $|x-q|<S$."
- Also you use both $r$ and $x=r$, not wrong but why bother with two
  symbols?
- where in the proof did you say that $q\neq 0$?
- Where is the concluding sentence?

Comment: thanks for the "technicality". i was just asking if i did something fundamentally wrong, wrong concept or wrong method etc

Comment: To me, not using the correct quantifiers is fundamentally wrong. If I was marking this, I would make sure to not give it full marks @Meg

Comment: While quantifiers are the key here it is best if they are understood in natural language rather than in technical language and symbols. +1 for raising fine points.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is correct, except for a minor change. To show that $f$ is not continuous at a point $q \in \mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$, we need to show that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$, such that, for each $S > 0$, there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x - q| < S$, and $|f(x) - q| > \epsilon$. However, you have proved precisely this fact in your final step by taking $\epsilon = \frac{q}{2}$, and this is correct.

Comment: thanks harishc07